# popCurrent called on ModelAsController controller, but it wasn't at the top of the stack - Silverstripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

A website built in Silverstripe 3.0 seems to be logging this error quite often:

**"E_USER_WARNING: popCurrent called on ModelAsController controller, but it wasn't at the top of the stack"**

The stack trace:
*/framework/control/Controller.php (447)

/cms/code/controllers/ModelAsController.php (77)/framework/control/Director.php (296)

/framework/control/Director.php (119)/framework/main.php (126)*

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @micmania1 this issue was [resolved](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/2467) by the framework maintainers a month after posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

Is that the full log statement you get? I've got quite a lot of similar statements (still 2.4 but that should be the same issue):

```
Warning at sapphire/core/control/Controller.php line 454:
popCurrent called on ModelAsController controller,
but it wasn't at the top of the stack
(http://www.foo.com/valid-page/piwik/libs/open-flash-chart/php-ofc-library/ofc_upload_image.php?name=wp.php)
```

So `http://www.foo.com/valid-page` really exists and some bot checks if you are running a vulnerable software (Piwik in this case). As long as you aren't using this software and are running the latest version, you should be find.

Most automated attacks I've seen target WordPress, Piwik, etc or some common extension (Timthumb); never something SilverStripe specific because it's not common enough to make it a good target of automated scans.

Comment: You could probably change the error_reporting level to E_ERROR but that would mean not logging any warning which is probably not a good idea. There's an open issue on github if you don't mind getting your hands dirty? https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/2467